# Network diagrams, what percentage means

Tags: networking

I'm doing a network diagram (dependency diagram) and I came across a node that can start if it's predecessor is 50% complete. So I5 can start once B5 is 50% done. Now I want to calculate the EST and LST for I5. Suppose B5 EST is 10 and it's duration is 6, does that make I5 EST 8 (50%) or 16.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: @Mat Actually, it's part of project managment/software development planning. So I'd say edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to draw something nice on hand right now, but you should just draw a time line on a sheet of paper, then draw everything on it with earliest starting times and the like.

This sounds rather odd without using any real units to me, so I'll just use "seconds". Of course you can do it without, but it's easier for me.

Just to sum up all conditions:

- B5 starts not earlier than 10 seconds into the process.
- B5's duration is 6 seconds.
- I5 requires B5 do be 50% complete.

Now to do the math part:

- B5 is 50% complete after 3 seconds.
- Remember that B5 won't start earlier than 10 seconds into the process.
- So the earliest time I5 could start would be 13 seconds into the process (10 + 3).

Just remember completion doesn't mean "it's x% on the way to start". Instead it's usually meant like "it's x% done after starting".